# How to mutate a column using dplyr with a value when any of the columns contain a 1 otherwise 0

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

```
events <- structure(list(ID = c(3049951, 3085397, 3204081, 3262134, 
3467254), TVTProcedureStartDate = structure(c(16210, 16238, 16322, 
16420, 16546), class = "Date"), DCDate = structure(c(16213, 16250, 
16326, 16426, 16560), class = "Date"), CE_EventOccurred = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), CE_EventDate = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Annular Dissection (In Hospital)` = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Aortic Dissection (In Hospital)` = c(0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L), `Atrial Fibrillation (In Hospital)` = c(0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 1L), `Bleeding at Access Site (In Hospital)` = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Cardiac Arrest (In Hospital)` = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L), `Conduction/Native Pacer Disturbance Req ICD (In Hospital)` = c(0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L), `Conduction/Native Pacer Disturbance Req Pacer (In Hospital)` = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Endocarditis (In Hospital)` = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L), `GI Bleed (In Hospital)` = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Hematoma at Access Site (In Hospital)` = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Ischemic Stroke (In Hospital)` = c(0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L), `Major Vascular Complications (In Hospital)` = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Minor Vascular Complication (In Hospital)` = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Mitral Leaflet Injury - detected during surgery (In Hospital)` = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Mitral Subvalvular Injury -detected during surgery (In Hospital)` = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `New Requirement for Dialysis (In Hospital)` = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Other Bleed (In Hospital)` = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L), `Perforation with or w/o Tamponade (In Hospital)` = c(1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Retroperitoneal Bleeding (In Hospital)` = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Single Leaflet Device Attachment (In Hospital)` = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Unplanned Other Cardiac Surgery or Intervention (In Hospital)` = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Unplanned Vascular Surgery or Intervention (In Hospital)` = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L)), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -5L), vars = "NCDRPatientID", labels = structure(list(
    NCDRPatientID = c(3049951, 3085397, 3204081, 3262134, 3467254
    )), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L), vars = "NCDRPatientID", labels = structure(list(
    NCDRPatientID = c(3049951, 3085397, 3204081, 3262134, 3467254, 
    3467324, 3510387, 3586037, 3661089, 3668621, 3679485, 3737916, 
    3738064, 3960141, 4006862, 4018241, 4019056, 4025174, 4027490, 
    4050900, 4051101, 4096816, 4097119, 4097146, 4097180, 4098426, 
    4106410, 4109968, 4147466, 4198427, 4198450, 4198458, 4204554, 
    4208053, 4213116, 4218802, 4218854, 4223378, 4223415, 4243959, 
    4316979, 4341660, 4348676, 4413567, 4419513, 4421948, 4422768, 
    4426483, 4430159, 4431211, 4433156, 4433406, 4433988)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-53L), vars = "NCDRPatientID", labels = structure(list(NCDRPatientID = c(3049951, 
3085397, 3204081, 3262134, 3467254, 3467324, 3510387, 3586037, 
3661089, 3668621, 3679485, 3737916, 3738064, 3960141, 4006862, 
4018241, 4019056, 4025174, 4027490, 4050900, 4051101, 4096816, 
4097119, 4097146, 4097180, 4098426, 4106410, 4109968, 4147466, 
4198427, 4198450, 4198458, 4204554, 4208053, 4213116, 4218802, 
4218854, 4223378, 4223415, 4243959, 4316979, 4341660, 4348676, 
4413567, 4419513, 4421948, 4422768, 4426483, 4430159, 4431211, 
4433156, 4433406, 4433988)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-53L), vars = "NCDRPatientID", drop = TRUE), indices = list(0L, 
    1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10:12, 13L, 14L, 15L, 
    16:17, 18L, 19:21, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25:26, 27L, 28L, 29:30, 
    31L, 32:33, 34L, 35:38, 39L, 40:41, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 
    47L, 48:50, 51:53, 54L, 55L, 56L, 57L, 58L, 59:60, 61L, 62L, 
    63:64, 65:66, 67:68, 69L, 70L, 71:72, 73L), drop = TRUE, group_sizes = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L), biggest_group_size = 4L), indices = list(0L, 
    1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 
    15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 
    27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 
    39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 
    51L, 52L), drop = TRUE, group_sizes = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L
), biggest_group_size = 1L), indices = list(0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), drop = TRUE, group_sizes = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), biggest_group_size = 1L)
```

From this data, I need to create a column that has value 1 if any of the columns which ends in `(in-hospital)` contains 1 else 0.

I tried multiple things but either doesn't work or displays error

```
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : Evaluation error: NA/NaN argument.
event %>% mutate(TR = rowSums(select_(.,6:n)))

Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : Column `TR` must be length 1 (the group size), not 53
event %>% mutate(TR = rowSums(.[6:ncol(.)]))
```

And some other variations of it to see if I can understand or make some sense, but it keeps running into the similar errors and problems

Another thing i tried was the following which seems to do the row sums, but it also adds the ID even when I'm doing the following:

```
event %>% select(6:27) %>% rowSums()
```

but it added the ID with the `1`s and `0`s from columns `6` to `27` for each row. Not sure why it's doing this.

I want the results as a data frame with the same data, but also a column with 1s if any of the columns from 6 to 27 contains 1 otherwise 0

Comment: `events$newcol <- select(events, matches("In Hospital")) %>% rowSums()` worked for me (once I fixed the errors mentioned in my next comment).

Comment: BTW, your data is grouped, which may slow down some `dplyr`-centric operations. Also, I got an warning about `Detecting old grouped_df format`, and an error `Column `NCDRPatientID` is unknown`, suggesting several other things going on that render this not-completely-reproducible. So my commented solution may not work if your version of `dplyr` is significantly older than mine (0.8.0.1).

Comment: @r2evans, thank you for pointing it out. I think I made an error when I copied and pasted the data and accidentally removed the NCDR patient column. But this still works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before I developed my solution, I ran the following code to ungroup your data.

```
library(dplyr)

events <- events %>% ungroup()
```

#### Solution 1: rowSums with selected columns

The idea of this solution is to use `rowSums` to add all the numbers from the selected columns, determine if the sum is larger than 0, and then convert the logical vector to an integer vector (with 1 or 0).

There are many ways to select the columns. We can select based on column numbers.

```
events2 <- events %>% mutate(Col = as.integer(rowSums(select(., 6:27)) > 0))
events2$Col 
# [1] 1 1 1 1 1
```

We can use `ends_with`.

```
events2 <- events %>% mutate(Col = as.integer(rowSums(select(., ends_with("(In Hospital)"))) > 0))
events2$Col 
# [1] 1 1 1 1 1
```

We can use `matches`. The regular expression `\\(In Hospital\\)$` indicates the string at the end.

```
events2 <- events %>% mutate(Col = as.integer(rowSums(select(., matches("\\(In Hospital\\)$"))) > 0))
events2$Col 
# [1] 1 1 1 1 1
```

We can use `contains`, but notice that the target string does not need to be in the end of the column names.

```
events2 <- events %>% mutate(Col = as.integer(rowSums(select(., contains("(In Hospital)"))) > 0))
events2$Col 
# [1] 1 1 1 1 1
```

#### Solution 2: apply with max

Since the numbers from the target columns are all `1` or `0`, we can use `apply` with `max` to get the maximum, which will be `1` if there ara any `1`, or `0`. All the ways to use the `select` function as was shown above will also work here. Below I presented one way to do this.

```
events2 <- events %>% mutate(Col = apply(select(., ends_with("(In Hospital)")), 1, max))
events2$Col 
# [1] 1 1 1 1 1
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. +1 for explaining the process and showing different methods to do so.

Answer (score 2):

It is not a dplyr way, but it also works:

```
events$new_col <- 0
events$new_col[rowSums(events[, grep("In Hospital", colnames(events))]) >= 1] <- 1
```

Answer (score 2):

A solution from base `R` using `apply()`

```
cols <- grep("in hospital", colnames(events), ignore.case = T)
apply(events[, cols], 1, function(x) ifelse(any(x == 1), 1, 0))

# [1] 1 1 1 1 1
```